# How to visualize ranked voting data?

Tags: data-visualization, ranking, excel

[image: Visual Representation of how we obtained ranked data]

I've done a couple of these exercises asking individuals to rank their priorities 1 (being most important) to 3 (not as important).  We have approximately 6 of these charts (all converted into a spreadsheet).  I've seen a few posts similar to this but they all have many more ranking values and given that this only has 3, I'm not sure the best charts or visualizations to use to generate any insights.

I had originally intended to just make simple charts in excel or Tableau although if there are better methods using R, I can learn.

Here's the data:

```
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Weather Events  3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Income Inequality   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   1
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   2
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   3
Lincoln Park    9/18/2016   Preservation of Natural Resources   3
```

Comment: Can you provide the data in a more user-friendly format (ie, paste in the numbers)? People aren't going to want to count these dots.

Comment: Yes, I just posted the numbers (sorry about that).

Comment: That's OK. Do you know which rankings came from which student? In statistical terms, the rankings are 'non-independent'; it might be worthwhile to take that into account in the figure (or might not).

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not have the data organized by student.  I played around with this a bit and decided to create a pivot table comparing the location of event (in this case Lincoln Park) and topic area (Income Inequality, Weather Events & Preservation of Natural Resources).  With those values, created a stacked bar chart.  The chart is misleading though because the largest value on the chart is actually the 3rd ranked topic area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Some notes: I don't really know pivot tables, so I'm not working with that.  Nonetheless, these should be quite doable in Excel.  Also, your rankings don't all add up to 40.  I'm guessing there is some mistake there.  So, I switched a ranking of 1 for Inequality to a ranking of 2.*

```r
## original:  
# 25  12     4  41
#  8    20  11  39
#  7     8  25  40
# 40    40  40  

## new:
#     Preservation Inequality Weather Sum
# 1             25         11       4  40
# 2              8         21      11  40
# 3              7          8      25  40
# Sum           40         40      40 120
```

---

I would use stacked bar charts here.  There is a choice between whether you want the bars to represent the concerns or the rankings.  Both are justifiable, but I would guess concerns might be more appropriate for your case.  Either way, I would sort the bars in descending order.

[image]

[image]

---

An interesting issue here is that we are ignoring the non-independence that must exist in the data.  (Of course, in this case, we don't actually know the pattern of dependence.)  I might generate some artificial dependence and play with it in a future addition.